# Accessing method variables

Tags: python, inheritance

I've created a house escape game that has demons in it. When you enter a room with a demon, I call the combat method. Everything is working fine except I'm having issues understanding how to decrement lives when killed in combat. The combat is dice-based. I've tried using a boolean flag to mark when a player has been killed to decrement but I can't seem to access that result to then decrement the life for the player. Any help is appreciated. Thank you stack community.

I've tried to also handle the life decrementation inside of the method but that doesn't work for me neither when I call the variable outside of the combat method.

```
import random


def showInstructions():
    # Display main menu and the commands to use in the game
    print('''
Hill House
----------
Commands:
go [direction]
get [item] 
    ''')


def showStatus():
    # Display the current player status
    print('-----------------------------')
    print('You are in the ' + currentRoom + ' with ' + str(currentLives) + ' lives')
    # Display the items currently in players inventory
    print('Inventory : ' + str(inventory))
    # This if statement displays items in the room should there be any
    if "item" in rooms[currentRoom]:
        print('You see a ' + rooms[currentRoom]['item'])
        print("--------------------------------------")


def player():
    currentLives = 5
    return currentLives


def combat():
    # combat function
    print('DEFEND YOURSELF OR ATTEMPT TO FLEE!')
    print('''   
-----------------------------------------
Commands:
To fight the Demon - roll 
To attempt to escape the Demom - flee 
    ''')
    playersCommand = input('>')
    demonsRoll = random.randrange(10)
    if playersCommand == 'roll':
        playersRoll = random.randrange(10)
        if playersRoll >= demonsRoll:
            print('The Demon has rolled a ' + str(demonsRoll) + ' and you rolled a '
                  + str(playersRoll) + '. You have killed the demon!')
            del rooms[currentRoom]['demon']
            fightResult = True

        else:
            print('The Demon has rolled a ' + str(demonsRoll) + ' and you rolled a '
                  + str(playersRoll) + '. You have been killed!')
            fightResult = False

    else:
        playersCommand == 'flee'
        playersRoll = random.randrange(10)
        if playersRoll >= demonsRoll:
            print('The Demon has rolled a ' + str(demonsRoll) + ' and you rolled a '
                  + str(playersRoll) + '. YOU HAVE GOT AWAY!')
        else:
            print('The Demon has rolled a ' + str(demonsRoll) + ' and you rolled a '
                  + str(playersRoll) + '. You have been killed!')
        del inventory[:]
        fightResult = False


# inventory that is empty
inventory = []

# Starting lives
currentLives = 5

# Rooms
rooms = {

    'Master Bathroom': {
        'west': 'Master Bedroom',
        'item': 'Green Spirit Stone',
        'demon': 'demon'
    },
    'Master Bedroom': {
        'east': 'Master Bathroom',
        'west': 'Up Stairs',
        'item': 'Glowing Red Crystal'
    },
    'Guest Bedroom': {
        'west': 'Library'
    },
    'Library': {
        'north': 'Up Stairs',
        'east': 'Guest Bedroom',
        'item': 'Mirror Stone'
    },
    'Up Stairs': {
        'north': 'Ball Room',
        'east': 'Master Bedroom',
        'west': 'Hall',
        'south': 'Library'
    },
    'Ball Room': {
        'east': 'Dinning Room',
        'south': 'Up Stairs',
        'west': 'Dinning Room',
        'item': 'Pale Purple Crystal'
    },
    'Hall': {
        'north': 'Dinning Room',
        'east': 'Exit',
        'west': 'Up Stairs',
        'south': 'Kitchen'
    },
    'Dinning Room': {
        'east': 'Ball Room',
        'south': 'Hall',
        'item': 'Tall Tale Heart'
    },
    'Kitchen': {
        'north': 'Hall',
        'item': 'sacred water',
        'demon': 'demon'
    },
    'Exit': {
        'east': 'Hall'
    }
}
# The defined starting point
currentRoom = 'Hall'

# Display the instructions
showInstructions()

# game loop
while True:


    showStatus()

    # get the player's position
    move = ''
    while move == '':
        move = input('>')

    move = move.split()

    # if they type 'go' first
    if move[0] == 'go':
        # check that they are allowed wherever they want to go
        if move[1] in rooms[currentRoom]:
            # set the current room to the new room
            currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom][move[1]]
        # there is no door (link) to the new room
        else:
            print('You can\'t go that way!')

    # if they type 'get' first
    if move[0] == 'get':
        # if the room contains an item, and the item is the one they want to get
        if "item" in rooms[currentRoom] and move[1] in rooms[currentRoom]['item']:
            # add the item to their inventory
            inventory += [move[1]]
            # display a helpful message
            print(move[1] + ' got!')
            # delete the item from the room
            del rooms[currentRoom]['item']
        # otherwise, if the item isn't there to get
        else:
            # tell them they can't get it
            print('Can\'t get ' + move[1] + '!')

    if 'demon' in rooms[currentRoom]:
        print("YOUR UNDER ATTACK BY A DEMON!")
        print('')
        combat()
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You need to provide some form of a [mcve]. Note, you've written no methods here, just normal functions. Try to write a small example that doesn't have anything to do with your game but demonstrates the issue. It sounds like you need to *return some value* from your function, or use global variables (which is very bad design in this case).

Comment: For do it 1st make ``currentlives`` **global**, and later on the condition make ``currentlives -= 1``

Comment: I notice the `combat` function stores a value to the local variable `fightResult`, but never does anything with it.

Comment: Hey everyone, thank you for the responses. @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry for being too vague. Here is what I asking for help with. In the function "combat", it auto-generates a dice roll for the player and for the demon. If the demon wins, I want to decrement a life from the player. I have a global variable of "currentLives". I would ideally like to move the global variable into a seperate function but at this point I just want to get one issue handled. 

What is happening is that when I kill the demon, currentLives doesn't decrement like it's expected.

Comment: @deoncagadoes Thank for the help. I know it's not good to use global vars but your suggestion worked. Thanks again!